# PHP Ratchet websocket handshake failing

Tags: php, networking, ratchet

Just started using ratchet. When I firstly tested it, it worked fine with websockets, got requests etc. But now I am doing the same as I did, but the request (onOpen) isn't even getting requested, and I am getting this JS error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404
```

jscode:

```
var conn = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080");
conn.onopen = function(e) {
    console.log("Connected!");
    conn.send("hello server");
};
conn.onmessage = function (e) {
    console.log(e.data);
};
```

And my source code:

Main file:

```
require __DIR__ . "../../library/loader.php";
require __DIR__ . "../../vendor/autoload.php";

error_reporting(E_ALL);

use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer,
    Ratchet\Http\HttpServer,
    Ratchet\Server\IoServer;

use bin\library\AsynChatServer;

$server = IoServer::factory(
    new HttpServer(
        new WsServer(
            new AsynChatServer()
        )), 8080);

$server->run();
```

And the server class:

```
namespace bin\library;

use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface,
    Ratchet\ConnectionInterface,
    Ratchet\Server\IoConnection;

use bin\library\database\Db;

use bin\library\model\Client,
    bin\library\model\PacketManager;

class AsynChatServer implements MessageComponentInterface {

    private $clients;

    /** @var Db */
    private $database;

    /** @var PacketManager */

    private $packets;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->clients = array();
        $this->database = new Db();
        $this->packets = new PacketManager($this);

        AsynChatServer::println("Server has started up.");
    }

    /**
     * When a new connection is opened it will be passed to this method
     * @param  ConnectionInterface $conn The socket/connection that just connected to your application
     * @throws \Exception
     */

    function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn)
    {
        echo "request";
        /** @var $client Client */
        $client = new Client($conn);
        $this->clients[$conn->resourceId] = $client;
        AsynChatServer::println("New client accepted: " + $client->getClient()->getRemoteAddress());
    }

    /**
     * This is called before or after a socket is closed (depends on how it's closed).  SendMessage to $conn will not result in an error if it has already been closed.
     * @param  ConnectionInterface $conn The socket/connection that is closing/closed
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn)
    {
        // TODO: Implement onClose() method.
    }

    /**
     * If there is an error with one of the sockets, or somewhere in the application where an Exception is thrown,
     * the Exception is sent back down the stack, handled by the Server and bubbled back up the application through this method
     * @param  ConnectionInterface $conn
     * @param  \Exception $e
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e)
    {
        // TODO: Implement onError() method.
    }

    /**
     * Triggered when a client sends data through the socket
     * @param  \Ratchet\ConnectionInterface $from The socket/connection that sent the message to your application
     * @param  string $msg  The message received
     * @throws \Exception
     */

    function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg)
    {
        /** @var $client Client */
        $client = $this->clients[$from->resourceId];
        AsynChatServer::println("Paccket received from: " . $client->getClient()->getRemoteAddress());
        $this->packets->processPacket($client, $msg);
    }

    public static function println($message) {
        echo $message . "\n";
    }

    public function getDB() {
        return $this->database;
    }

}
```

Is there something wrong? Could the library be corrupted so I need to re-set it up?
This is the output i get when I run:

```
c:\xampp1\php>php c:/xampp1/htdocs/AsynChat/bin/AsynChat.php
Server has started up.
```

Nothing else when I connect, no signle error.

What is wrong?

NETSTAT -A:

```
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         Ben-╧╩:0               LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         Ben-╧╩:0               LISTENING
```

My App.php constructor:

```
public function __construct($httpHost = 'localhost', $port = 8080, $address = '127.0.0.1', LoopInterface $loop = null) {
```

Comment: Ratchet only gives a 404 inside the Router component (which you are not using). The fact that the browser got an HTTP response with a 404 status code leads me to believe you're connecting to a different running service on that port, not Ratchet.